# Can we compare two saved profiles of performance panel of google chrome tool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to compare between two saved performance panel profiles of google chrome dev tool?

Comment: would be a really nice feature

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question and I'm sure you've already answered it, but it might help someone else who has the same problem.

The answer is yes, to make a comparison you have to create two profiles and then in the top menu drop down the options where it says "summary" and choose the option "compare" and on the right side where it says "class filter" you can choose which of the profiles you have created you are going to compare with.
[image: Can we compare two saved profiles of performance panel of google chrome tool]